# Windows 10: How to split the screen in two?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I need to compare two chrome windows pages, having the same size, in **landscape** (top/bottom !*not the portrait* left/right) format. So I need to show them stacked and take the max of the screen's space.

Unfortunately the Window's function "show windows stacked" does not stake them on the full screen, but it takes only 2/3 of the screen's height.... something like this:

[image]

Is there another way to split the screen in two?

Comment: You can use the `Win + Left/Right/Up/Down` arrow keys to make the window take up quarter of the screen (either top-left, top-right, bottom-left or bottom-right) and then  you can use your mouse to extend the window horizontally so that it takes up the screen width. The horizontal extension should snap the window to the screen so should give you to half screen configuration you seek.

Comment: E.g. 1. Open a window -> 2. Press `Win + Up` to maximise the window -> 3. Press `Win + right` to make the window take up right half of screen -> 4. Press `Win + Down` to make window use quarter of the screen (bottom right) -> 5. Use mouse to extend left of window to use the screen width.

Comment: yes, the special remark is that I don't need left and right, but top and bottom... that is the little difficulty... but I don't know how, sometimes the "show windows stacked" uses the full height of the screen, but I can't reproduce...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Natively, it seems, you can't.**

You can work around this using the left/right/up/down snapping capabilities plus a final use of your mouse.

1. Open your two windows
2. Bring focus to one of your windows
3. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to maximize the window
4. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to snap the window to the right half of the screen
5. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to snap the window to the bottom right quarter of the screen
6. Repeat 1 - 5 with your second window. Note: on step 5 press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to position the window to the top right quarter of the screen
7. Use your mouse to extend both windows so that they extend the width of your screen. Note: I have noticed that, even with multiple screens, Windows 10, whilst extending a window horizontally, will snap the window to the full width of the screen. If you need to extend past the screen (with multipe monitors, for example) then you can continue moving your mouse and it will un-snap and continue extending.

Comment: OK, so, in the last move, we need to use the mouse to fill it till the end of the screen... so "manual work", but is already a great way! thanks a lot

Comment: @Serge - Unfortunately, yes, the final step is a manual one... You might want to use the likes of a third party macro solution like has been suggested, if you want full automation.

Comment: also, remark, to split left and right there are "magnifiers", you use your mouse to bring your window on the top-right, or top-left corners of the screen, then a little "magnifier" circle appears, and you can "magnify" your left or right half of the screen with your window... but this is not the case if you want to do top/bottom

Comment: on step 3 you mentioned `Win` + `Up Arrow` but on step 6 you have written `Win` + `Up Key`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Typo, yes. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has never had this function, for some unknown reason.
Snap to right, left, or quadrant exists, but the logical hotkey for snap-to-top
does rather maximize the window.

So you need a third-party tool for it, and here is a little list :

- [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/)
- [AquaSnap](https://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap)
- [WindowGrid](http://windowgrid.net/)

For some of them you may need to specify the hotkey you would like to use,
but don't overstep on the ones used by Windows.

There are also various AutoHotKey scripts running around for this purposes,
which you may search for if none of the above is satisfactory.

Comment: yes, thanks, I see, .... however I am not too hot to install a third party software just for adjusting the size of my window... is seems strange for me... )

Comment: I currently have dozens of installed products that adjust Windows to my liking. When I don't find acceptable something that Microsoft has published, I correct it by a third-party product or by one I write myself. For example, I don't use Edge.

Comment: haha, I use Edge just to test websites display, because I am a web-dev, so, did you create your web-browser?

Comment: usually third party tools bring unneeded trash home, so less they are, better is for the computer's health...

Comment: Edge: Good idea, might do it when I have some free time. Thrash: Not at all if you don't choose a shady product.

Comment: I'm currently a web dev and we just don't care about edge nor IE. Our customers use mainly chrome and Safari, if you use edge or IE you'll be used to see broken things on websites anyways and if they implemented well the new IE they should have been fit to the standard features so no much to take care about. Safari is the main buggy shit those days :c

Comment: Microsoft's [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) project actually has a utility to help with window snapping, if trusted first-party add-ons are important in your environment

Answer (score 0):

How I like to do that with [Windows Snap](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) ([backup link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-snap-assist-windows-10-0)):

1. **Drag Window/app to corner of screen** (mouse pointer has to hit it). This changes app to take up a quarter of the screen
2. **Resize the Window on its left or right side so it takes up the whole horizontal** space. So the app should now be horizontally half of the screen (on top or bottom)
3. **Repeat** steps with second app & opposite corner

Likely a repeat of @[Kinnectus answer](https://superuser.com/a/1363834/160219), I skimmed it. His seemed to be focused on keyboard shortcuts, consider my answer a simply mouse-only method

Answer (score -2):

Please read this link.

https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-enable-windows-up-down-to-split-apps-on-vertical-monitor

It work for me.
Best regrads
Thammarat Thongloi.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1095702)